# Deploying circles on 2D space to cover most of points

Tags: computational-geometry

My question is related to this one

[Minimize number of circles to cover set of points](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63697/minimize-number-of-circles-to-cover-set-of-points)

In a 2D space, I have a set of points. I can deploy up to $k$ circles with radius $r$ to the space, and my goal is to maximize the number of points that will be put inside these circles. There are two cases:
a) Either the circles cannot overlap
b) Or they can.

I am completely stuck here. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start (for the case where you allow overlap):

For every point $v$, start by drawing a circle with radius $r$ such that $v$ is at its center.

Now, observe the following nice property: Let $d$ be a point in space such that it is contained in $m$ of the **drawn** circles. Then, placing a circle with radius $r$ with its middle at $d$ would cover those $m$ points.

Hence, your algorithm should *start* by "drawing" the $n$ circles, and applying an algorithm to find all intersections between the drawn triangles and to get the number of intersections in them.